# Anime.js about first example

Tags: anime.js

According to http://animejs.com/documentation/ first example :

```
<script>
var cssSelector = anime({
  targets: '#cssSelector .el',
  translateX: 250
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="cssSelector">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="square el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

About 'anime.js code', I have an opinion that might not apply css attribute for class="square" in HTML for the 'anime.js code'. Thus, I add square.

```
<style>
.square {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Square viewed, however nothing happened for any movement.
Do you have any advice on this example?

Comment: Also, I already run completed examples to confirm anime CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine - I would guess you have forgotten to include jQuery.

```js
var cssSelector = anime({
  targets: '#cssSelector .el',
  translateX: 250
});
```

```css
.square {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="cssSelector">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="square el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```